# lcd monitor image flickers every once in a while

Tags: display, vga

I have a laptop with vga out that I connect to my monitor. This is as an extended desktop(dell 2007FP). My screen resolution is 1600x1200(60hz)

Every once in a while the screen flickers sideways, as in the window shakes left to right very quickly.

I have Intel hd graphics 4000 as the integrated graphics card driving this. I've updated the driver, but that still doesn't fix anything.

When i drop the resolution, this goes away, but i'd like to use it at the monitor's highest resolution

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a monitor/connection issue. Have you tried using another VGA cable or another monitor? Every time I have had a shaky screen, it was either the monitor or the connection. If it were the graphics card, I assume your laptop screen and extended monitor would shake--Not just one or the other.

Comment: just found out that lowering the resolution fixes this issue. But I'd still like the higher res

Comment: Were you exceeding the monitor's resolution? If not, does your laptop have anything but crappy ol' VGA?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely because of the analog video connection.  If you haven't done so already, try a different VGA cable, and make sure it's a high-quality shielded cable (usually about 1/4" diameter).  If you have a choice between a longer cable and a shorter cable which are otherwise of equal quality, the shorter one may give you better results.

You should also try hooking the monitor up to a different computer and/or hooking up a different monitor (with at least the same resolution) and check whether if it still exhibits the same behavior.

A better solution would be to use your monitor's digital (DVI) input instead of the analog (VGA) input.

If your laptop has DVI or HDMI out, try using the monitor's DVI input instead of the VGA input.  You can get a DVI-to-HDMI adapter or cable if necessary.

If the laptop doesn't have a digital video output, you can get a USB-to-DVI or USB-to-HDMI video adapter so you can use the monitor's DVI input.